# Ajax.beginform posts null values to controller

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, null, form-submit

I have searched quite a bit but have yet to find an answer.. 
I have a partial view with a form:

```
@model PetDate.Models.ProfileDataModel

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateProfileInfo", "Profile", new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post", OnFailure = "", OnSuccess = "" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.FullName, new { @class = "text-info" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.FullName, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "text-info" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Email, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "email" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.BirthDay, new { @class = "text-info" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.BirthDay, new { @class = "form-control", @type = "datetime" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "text-info" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.Username, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.AddressText, new { @class = "text-info" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AddressText, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "adresse" })


        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Postal, new { @id = "postalAddress" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Street, new { @id = "streetAddress" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.HouseNumber, new { @id = "houseNumberAddress" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.story, new { @id = "storyAddress" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.roomPlacement, new { @id = "roomPlacementAddress" })

    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "text-info" })
        @Html.TextAreaFor(x => x.Description, new { @class = "initTinyMCE" })
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-warning btn-lg" >Opdatér information</button>
    </div>
}
```

This form posts to my controller, but when i look at what i get in the controller, all the values says null.

My controller:

```
namespace PetDate.Controllers
{
    public class ProfileController : MasterController
    {

        [ValidateInput(false)]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UpdateProfileInfo(ProfileDataModel data)
        {
            int ownerID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["userID"]);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                using (var context = new ModelContainer())
                {
                    var ownerProfile = context.Owners.Where(x => x.ID == ownerID).FirstOrDefault();
                    var ownerLogin = context.Logins.Where(x => x.Owner_ID == ownerID).FirstOrDefault();

                    Address ownerAddress = null;

                    if (data.story != 0 && data.roomPlacement != string.Empty)
                    {
                        ownerAddress = context.Addresses.Where(x => x.Postal == data.Postal && x.Street == data.Street && x.Housenumber == Convert.ToInt32(data.HouseNumber) && x.Story == Convert.ToInt32(data.story) && x.Door == data.roomPlacement).FirstOrDefault();
                    }
                    else { 
                        ownerAddress = context.Addresses.Where(x => x.Postal == data.Postal && x.Street == data.Street && x.Housenumber == Convert.ToInt32(data.HouseNumber)).FirstOrDefault();
                    }


                    if (ownerProfile != null && ownerLogin != null)
                    {
                        // update content.
                        ownerProfile.FullName = data.FullName;
                        ownerProfile.Email = data.Email;
                        ownerProfile.Birthday = data.BirthDay;
                        ownerProfile.Description = data.Description;
                        ownerProfile.ProfilePicture = data.ProfilePicture;
                        ownerLogin.UserName = data.Username;

                        if (ownerAddress != null)
                        {   // already created the address, just get the ID
                            ownerProfile.Address_FK = ownerAddress.ID;

                        }
                        else
                        {   // has not been created before, create new one.

                            var obj = new Address()
                            {
                                Postal = data.Postal,
                                Street = data.Street,
                                Housenumber = Convert.ToInt32(data.HouseNumber),
                                Story = data.story,
                                Door = data.roomPlacement != string.Empty ? data.roomPlacement : ""
                            };

                        }


                        context.SaveChanges();
                        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200, "ok");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "failure");
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(400, "failure");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The variable Data, has null values. 
I have an almost similar form, and controller, that handles some other things which works perfectly...

So i am a bit lost as why the values returned are simply null...

My model if interested:

```
public class ProfileDataModel
    {
        [Required]
        public string FullName { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public DateTime? BirthDay { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public string Email { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public string AddressText { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public string Postal { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Street { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int HouseNumber { get; set; }
        public int story { get; set; }
        public string roomPlacement { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ProfilePicture { get; internal set; }
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; internal set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: your setters are internal, so the model binder wont be able to set the properties

Comment: Internal setters may causing this issue because default model binder requires public setters. Change them to standard setters instead.

Comment: lol... that was it... had completely missed that!

Comment: @MikNiller if you make an answer, i will mark that as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your setters are marked internal, the model binder is unable to set the properties.

changing

```
 public string FullName { get; internal set; }
```

to

```
 public string FullName { get; set; }
```

should fix your problem

Answer (score 2):

The model binding doesn't work with `DefaultModelBinder` because you're using [`internal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/internal) set accessor with `public` get accessor in some properties like this:

```
public string FullName { get; internal set; }
```

The above definitions means:

- other codes within your application can read property value
- only **codes within same assembly as your application** may write new value to the property

Since `DefaultModelBinder` uses reflection to perform both reading and writing value into property's backend field (you can see in [its definition](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/DefaultModelBinder.cs)), both get and set accessors must be set to `public` to enable two-way model binding with automatic properties.

Therefore, all properties inside viewmodel class must have both get and set accessors defined as public to let property values assigned from HTML helpers inside view:

```
public string FullName { get; set; }
```